# how many integers between $1000$ and $9999$ is the sum of digits equal $11$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have already known that all cases is $\binom{13}{3}$, but I don' know how to handle the bad cases, such like putting $10$ objects in the first box.

Comment: Do you know about generating functions?

Comment: yes, but I dont know how to find the bad cases.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  You should explain how you showed that there are $\binom{13}{3}$ cases in which the digit sum is $11$ before those cases in which a digit larger than $9$ is excluded.  The way you wrote your answer, I initially thought you were claiming that there were $133$ such cases.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT

The numbers involved are simple enough that you can just manually count and exclude all cases where there are $10$ or $11$ balls in one box.  (It is simple mainly because you cannot have *two or more* boxes each with $10$ or $11$ balls, so you don't need inclusion-exclusion.)

Thanks to @N.F.Taussig for pointing out some subtlety I didn't realize.  Since the first digit is non-zero (first box has a ball), there is only $1$ way to put $11$ balls in one box.  And to have $10$ balls in one box, either that's the first box (and the last ball can be in any other box), or the first box contains $1$ ball and the $10$ balls are together in some other box.

Comment: so how many cases where 10 balls in one box and how many cases where 11 balls in one box. Thanks

Comment: (A) How many cases where $11$ balls in one box?  There are $11$ balls, they all go in one box, and there are $4$ boxes, so...  (B) If $10$ balls in one box, then the leftover one is in another box, so...

Comment: Be careful.  Since the leading digit must be at least $1$, it is only possible to place $11$ balls in the first box.  The remaining boxes can have at most $10$.